# Vertical profiles of water vapor

Tags: data-request, usa

Where can I access data for vertical atmosphere profiles? Specifically, I'm looking for measurements of water vapor as a function of altitude over the USA. It's a bonus if I can find vertical profiles for atmospheric gases (CO2, NO, etc.)